# Set global default component for vue routes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

In my Vue application I have multiple routes, but is there a way to load the component of the route in a specific component? So like a global component for all routes?

I have a Frontend.vue that has `<router-view></router-view>` where I want to load the component of the route. So I want to set this Frontend component as default route. Any tips/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Oh damn, I'm stupid. I completely forgot about my App.vue... That is exactly what I needed.